# Remove periods from the end of markdown paragraphs

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of posts written in markdown and I need to remove the periods from the end of every paragraph in each of them

The end of a paragraph in markdown is delimited by:

- 2 or more `\n`s *or*
- The end of the string

However, there are these edge cases

1. Ellipses
2. Acroynms (e.g., I don't want to drop the final period in "Notorious B.I.G." when it falls at the end of a paragraph). I think you can deal with this case by saying "don't remove the final period if it's preceded by a capital letter which is itself preceded by another period"
3. Special cases: `e.g.`, `i.e.`, `etc.`

Here's a regular expression that *matches* posts that have offending periods, but it doesn't account for (2) and (3) above:

`/[^.]\.(\n{2,}|\z)/`

Comment: If you alter ""don't remove the final period if it's preceded by a capital letter which is itself preceded by another period" to "don't remove the final period if it's preceded by a letter which is itself preceded by another period" you can capture a lot of (3) in (2), unfortunately, for things like 'etc.', you should / could have quite en extensive wordlist on your hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Ruby 1.8.7 compatible algorithm:

```
s = %{this is a paragraph.

this ends with an ellipsis...

this ends with etc.

this ends with B.I.G.

this ends with e.g.

this should be replaced.

this is end of text.}.strip

a = s.split(/\n{2,}/).each do |paragraph|
  next unless paragraph.match /\.\Z/
  next if paragraph.match /(\.[a-zA-Z]|etc|\.\.)\.\Z/
  paragraph.chop!
end.join("\n\n")

>> puts a
this is a paragraph

this ends with an ellipsis...

this ends with etc.

this ends with B.I.G.

this ends with e.g.

this should be replaced

this is end of text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\.[a-zA-Z]|etc|\.\.)\.(?=\n{2,}|\Z)
```

- `(?<!\.[a-zA-Z]|etc|\.\.)` - lookbehind to make sure that the period is not preceded by sequences like `.T`, `etc`, `..` (for ellipsis).
- `\.` the period
- `(?=\n{2,}|\Z)` lookahead to look for end of a markdown paragraph (two newlines or end of string)

Test:

```
s = """ths is a paragraph.

this ends with an ellipsis...

this ends with etc.

this ends with B.I.G.

this ends with e.g.

this should be replaced.

this is end of text."""
print s.gsub(/(?<!\.[a-zA-Z]|etc|\.\.)\.(?=[\n]{2,}|\Z)/, "") 
print "\n"
```

Output:

```
this is a paragraph

this ends with an ellipsis...

this ends with etc.

this ends with B.I.G.

this ends with e.g.

this should be replaced

this is end of text
```

Comment: Perfect! (Only my version of Ruby (1.8.7) doesn't support lookbehinds! Argh!)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a lookbehind? Even with more than 1 regular expression (I can't upgrade Ruby right now)?

Comment: @Horaz I haven't tested this; but you can replace `(\.[a-zA-Z]|etc|\.\.)\.(?=\n{2,}|\Z)` with `"\\1"`

Comment: Close, but it does the *opposite* of what we want (i.e., removes periods when part of ellipses, acrynoms, etc). See http://pastie.org/1056316 (what does `"\\1"` mean?)